Which annalus do we use when finding the Laurent series of $\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ at $z = -2$

Find the Laurent series of $\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ at $z = -2$

My question
When a question does not provide the annalus, like this one, does it mean that we need to find all possible laurent series?
I.e. we need to find the laurent series for the annalus $0<|z+2|<1$ and we need to find the laurent series for the annalus $|z+2|>1$ aswell?
Thank you in advance.

I suppose so, but the question is unclear.

I agree, unfortunately this is the whole question

It doesn't hurt to provide all possible answers, as there are only two of them.
